# Matlab: A new hope for a colon for cells?

Tags: matlab

I found myself doing some unnecessary cell conversions on a regular basis, and couldn't find a function to convert a cell to a comma-separated list. Can this be achieved with through function, rather than `myvar{:}`?

a) Is there a function to convert cells to comma-separated lists? 
b) there is a sensible way to reduce the 'annoying part' (see below) to a one-liner, possibly circumventing the cell-array conversion in the first place (given the setup of data/function is fixed/cannot be changed)?

```
%this is my data and (silly, silly...) plotting function (consider these as un-changeable/static)
myvar = randn(10,1); 
plot_it_already = @(varargin) cellfun(@(x,y) bar(x,y),num2cell(1:numel(varargin)),varargin,'un',0);
figure; hold on;

%this part is the annoying part (and the part I can change):
myvar=num2cell(myvar); %seemingly unncessary cell conversion
plot_it_already(myvar{:}) %<- ... just so we can feed the function with a comma separated list
```

Comment: I don’t understand your code. Why do you need a cell array to plot your data? I’m probably missing something here.

Comment: I mean, the only alternative I see would be `plot_it_already(myvar(1),myvar(2),myvar(3)...)`. The above assumes that it's more sensible to use cell-arrays to convert to comma-separated lists, i.e. `myvar=num2cell(myvar)`, then `plot_it_already(myvar{:})` to pass *all* data to the function. I guess this is as not commonly done as I presumed? I was just looking for a function that does `mycell{:}`, such as `make_comma_sep_list(mycell)`, but couldn't find (and since lack of answers, questioned if it's the sensible approach in the first place)

Comment: But my question is why does `plot_it_already` take a comma-separated list of values, rather than an array of values? If this is a fixed thing you need to use unchanged, you can always write a function that takes an array as input, and calls that function with its comma-separated list of values.

Comment: And your new comment makes me wonder, why is `make_comma_sep_list(mycell)` easier than `mycell{:}`?